# Find the number of points of where this function isn't differentiable.

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I want to find the number of points of where this function isn't differentiable:
 $$f(x) = \max\{4,1+x²,x²-1\} $$
I tried drawing a graph but it didn't help.

Comment: Since $x^{2} - 1 < x^{2} + 1 = 1 + x^{2}$ for all real $x$, you can simplify the expression for your function. :) But if drawing the graph didn't help, either the graph isn't accurate or there's something basic about differentiability you don't fully understand. Did you sketch $y = 4$ and $y = 1 + x^{2}$ separately, then "trace the higher of the two graphs"?

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that the functions 4, $1+x^2$ and $x^2-1$ are differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$. Now let's take a look at $f$. A function is differentiable iff it can be approximated very well by a line.

If you look at your drawn graph, you have a few points $a$ where
$$
\lim_{x\uparrow a} f'(x) \neq\lim_{x\downarrow a} f'(x)
$$
These points exactly are the points where this function is not differentiable.

Comment: ...note you can have $\lim_{x\rightarrow a^+}f'(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow a^-}f'(x)$ and $f$ not differentiable at $a$... you need to talk about continuity before $\lim_{x\rightarrow a^+}f'(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow a^-}f'(x)$ is relevant.

Comment: True, but in this case we take the maximum of continuous functions.